# Handling very large problems in cplex c++ concert api++ without running out of memory

Tags: c++, cplex

I have a very large LP problem which i am trying to solve in cplex using the c++ concert api. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
// Get environment
IloEnv env = model.getEnv();

// Set x variable
for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++){
    x.add(IloBoolVar(env));
}

// Set objective
IloNumExpr objective(env);
objective += x[0];
model.add(IloMinimize(env, objective));

// Add constraints
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    IloNumExpr some_expr(env);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
        some_expr += x[j];
    }
    IloRange constraint(env,0,some_expr,0);
    c.add(constraint);
}

model.add(x);
model.add(c);

// store
IloCplex cplex(model);
cplex.exportModel("lpex1.lp");
```

When i run it, the memory used becomes to large for my pc quickly, causing everything to crash. Is there a way on how to handle large problems like these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cplex concert c++ api: Mixing mismatch environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367715/cplex-concert-c-api-mixing-mismatch-environments)

Comment: (it's a perfect dup from same OP, asked a few hours ago)

Comment: What hardware (how much RAM), what operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling large LP in cplex: Saving IloRangeArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317585/handling-large-lp-in-cplex-saving-ilorangearray)

Comment: @YSC I don't see it as a duplicate. Although the code is the same, there the question is how to fix the mismatching environment error.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Linux ubuntu, 4 gb ram

Comment: @rkersh , It is a continuation of the same problem, although i think that me trying to find what is wrong and suggesting it will not give any good results, so i decided to ask the question in a more general form.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you're looking for, and maybe it's not your case, but when problems are very large it is sometimes an indication that they are poorly formulated.

Comment: @PhilippeOlivier I am certainly considering that, although the model i use comes almost directly from a reviewed paper. I am completely new with c++, so i think there is a high chance i am doing something wrong on that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following complete example:

```
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
ILOSTLBEGIN

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   IloEnv env;
   IloNumVarArray x(env);

   int numVars = 10000;
   int numCons = 1000000;

   if (argc == 3) {
      stringstream nvars(argv[1]);
      stringstream ncons(argv[2]);
      nvars >> numVars;
      ncons >> numCons;
   }

   // Set x variable
   for(int i = 0; i <= numVars; i++) {
      x.add(IloBoolVar(env));
   }

   // Set objective
   IloModel model(env);
   IloNumExpr objective(env);
   objective += x[0];
   model.add(IloMinimize(env, objective));

   // Add constraints
   IloRangeArray c(env);
   for (int i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
      IloNumExpr some_expr(env);
      for (int j = 0; j < numVars; j++) {
         some_expr += x[j];
      }
      c.add(some_expr == 0.0);
      some_expr.end();
   }

   model.add(c);

   std::cout << "Memory usage after creating constraints: "
             << env.getMemoryUsage() / (1024. * 1024.)
             << " MB" << std::endl;

   env.end();
   return 0;
}  // END main
```

It's basically the same as you're example, except we use the [getMemoryUsage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloEnv.html#method_getMemoryUsage)() method to print out how much memory we're using. If we compile and run this, we get output like the following:

```
$ ./test 10000 1000
Memory usage after creating constraints: 229.827 MB
```

Notice, that this is only for 1000 constraints. If I'm doing my math correctly, you'll need 1000 times more memory to build the model from your example snippet and that would be ~230 GB of RAM! This does not even include how much memory you'd really need to extract the model and then attempt to solve it.

Your computer with 4 GB is not going to work for this. In general, using the [CPLEX Callable Library](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/C/01_cAPI_title_synopsis.html) (aka the C API) will require a smaller memory footprint, but you have to work with the lower-level functions. However, that will not work for you in this case either, as you're trying to build a model that is just too big for your machine.

Comment: Thanks. Not what i wanted to hear, but if it is like this i have to find another solution.